# сравнение в словаре по особому ключу

Tags: c#, словари

Существует словарь частоты встречаемости подстрок в предложении, где ключ - это подстрока, а значение - сколько раз эта подстрока встречается в предложении.

```
var frequency = new Dictionary<string, int>();
frequency.Add("ab", 2);
frequency.Add("ad", 1);
frequency.Add("ig", 0);
frequency.Add("ac", 1);
```

Мне необходимо рассмотреть все ключи, начинающиеся с "a" и выбрать из них тот, чье значение больше других ему подобных (выбрать ту подстроку с началом на "a", которая чаще остальных встречается в предложении). 
Кто знает, как это можно сделать?

Comment: `frequency.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith('a')).OrderBy(x => x.Value).Last();` или если нужно просто значение, то `frequency.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith('a')).Max(x => x.Value);`

Comment: спасибо @EvgeniyZ

Comment: Вы хоть поймите что это за строка, а не бездумно копируйте ее...

Comment: конечно же, linq всему голова

Comment: Если вам подобное нужно делать часто и вам важна скорость, то вы можете рассмотреть другие структуры данных. Тот же trie будет побыстрее словаря работать на получение такой как вам надо информации.